# Can I make a list comprehension of this python code?

Tags: python

```
for i in os.listdir('./Python'):
    f=open(os.path.join('./Python',i)).read().split()
    g=[re.sub('[<TEI[.+]<body>]','',j)
    for j in f if re.sub('[<TEI[.+]<body>]','',j)]:
       open(os.path.join('./Python/',i),'w').write('\n'.join(g))
```

Can I make a list comprehension of this code?. Fixed the `for` loop.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation and line spacing? I tried, but didn't know where you wanted the `for` to end. You use `j` before assigning it in the for loop, so this code doesn't work.

Comment: The goal here seems to be to read and write files so it is more properly written as for loops like you've shown than as a list comprension. Since you don't actually want a list of things when you are done, the list comprehension would only be executed for its side effects, which is considered unpythonic.

Comment: Since I corrected this, the question did not go up. You can think second 'for' is in re.sub code. I just want to make that code more clear in 1 line.

Comment: Did I get that right?

Comment: No... I want to append all codes in 1 lines, or 1 list comprehension...

Comment: Okay, you can go back and edit to make it right. All I did was add indentation... but the best way to show how the right way is to do it yourself.

Comment: for i in os.listdir('./Python'):
    f=open(os.path.join('./Python',i)).read().split()
    g=[re.sub('[<TEI[.+]<body>]','',j)
    for j in f if re.sub('[<TEI[.+]<body>]','',j)]
    open(os.path.join('./Python/',i),'w').write('\n'.join(g))

Comment: This code was what I tried to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but it provides the concept.

```
opn = lambda i : open(os.path.join('./Python',i)).read().split()
lst = lambda i : [re.sub('[<TEI[.+]]','',j) for j in opn(i) if re.sub('[<TEI[.+]]','',j)] 
wrt = lambda i,g : open(os.path.join('./Python/',i),'w').write('\n'.join(lst(i)))
[(i,wrt(i)) for i in os.listdir('./Python')]
```

Here is single line

[(i,open(os.path.join('./Python/',i),'w').write('\n'.join([re.sub('[<TEI[.+]]','',j) for j in open(os.path.join('./Python',i)).read().split() if re.sub('[<TEI[.+]]','',j)] )) for i in os.listdir('./Python')]

Comment: Can you add my codes in just one list comprehension? I'm sorry, but I want a code that starts with [.

Comment: combined into single line... but very convoluted.

Comment: I got an error in 'for i in os.listdir('./Python')]' because of invalid syntax...